# git: pull specific branch, keep only the latest tree (without any history)

Tags: git, git-pull, gentoo

How can I pull a specific branch from a remote repository, checking out only the latest tree without keeping any history?

This question is specifically related to checking out Gentoo's Portage tree: I'd like to update my Portage tree, without keeping any history, minimizing the size of `/usr/portage/.git`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$ git clone --branch dotnet-mono-eclass-lat --depth 1 https://anongit.gentoo.org/git/repo/gentoo.git
```

From `man git-clone`:

> --branch <name>, -b <name>
>
> Instead of pointing the newly created HEAD to the branch pointed to by the cloned repository’s HEAD,
> point to <name> branch instead. In a non-bare repository, this is the branch that will be checked out.
>
> --depth <depth>
>
> Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions. A shallow
> repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into
> it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project with a long
> history, and would want to send in fixes as patches.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to provide the needed commands when updating an existing repository?

Comment: What do you mean by `existing repository`? Did you already clone `portage` repository using a regular `git clone` command?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The remote repository has already been cloned to `/usr/portage`.

Comment: IIUC, you already have an entire repository with all branches and history. In such case you can just create a new local branch off the remote branch with `git checkout <BRANCH_NAME>`.

Answer (score 2):

to download repository without history :
git clone --depth 1

To update already cloned shallow repository:

> git pull --depth 1 
>   or 
>   git pull --update-shallow